# Codeigniter 3 subdomain not working for other pages

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter-3

I have created sub-domain like this in Codeigniter 3

```
www.test.example.com
```

I have used this .htaccess and it's working only home page.

`www.test.exapmle.com` for other pages like `www.test.exapmle.com/page1` or `www.test.exapmle.com/page2`

.htaccess I used:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public_html/index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I am getting this error:

> the server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.

Answer (score 0):

In `.htaccess` file just insert the following code

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```